# Do i have to update the serialVersionUID for this change?

Tags: java, serialization, serialversionuid

If i change this method:

```
public void setCustom(Map<String, Object> custom) {
    this.custom = (LinkedHashMap<String, Object>)custom;
}
```

to:

```
public void setCustom(LinkedHashMap<String, Object> custom) {
    this.custom = custom;
}
```

do i have to update the serialVersionUID? Is it a compatible change or not?

Comment: You *never* 'have to update' the `serialVersionUID`, let alone in this case. You haven't changed the serializable fields of the class, at least not from what we've seen here: but the notion that you have to update the `serialVersionUID` when you do is fundamentally flawed. See the ['Object Versioning' chapter of the 'Java Object Serialization Specification'](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/serialization/spec/version.html#6678).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the serialization works with class member variables not with methods.
For full list of changes that must be taken into account see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/serialization/spec/version.html#6678).